# jQuery keyboard navigation : dysfunction with mouse

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I have a script for a keyboard navigation that partially works.

When I'm on the home page (top of page) and I press the "down" key on my keyboard the page scroll fine to the next section.
The problem is that if I scroll with my mouse in the middle of the page, or at the bottom of the page and I want to use the keyboard to get to the next section (on top or bottom) it doesn't work.
In fact I have a counter system that lets you navigate between sections $ ('.layout') but this system shows its limits.

So I'm confused and I need some help please. What can I add in my code for that my keyboard navigation works fine anywhere in the page ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/LPvS9/7/

```
// KEYBOARD NAV
$(function () {
    var positions = []
    $('.layout').each(function () {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset().top));
    })

    var count = 0
    var x = positions.length - 1
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                if (count >= x * (-1) && count !== 0) {
                    count--
                    $('#page').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: positions[count]
                    }, 700);
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault()
                }

                break;

            case 40:
                if (count <= x) {
                    count++
                    $('#page').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: positions[count]
                    }, 700);
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault()
                }

                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend against manipulating the default navigation implementations of browsers.

If that's not possible, I think the best solution in your case would be to make all keyboard navigation events based off the current scroll position.

One example would be to store all of the positions or divs that you want to travel to in some sort of container like an array. Then on a keypress event you would test where the current scroll position is with the below code and then react accordingly.

```
$('#page').scrollTop())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can monitor the scroll event and based on that update your count variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/LPvS9/21/

```
$("#page").scroll( function (event) {
    scrollTopPosition = $("#page").scrollTop()+$("#page").height();
    for (i=positions.length-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        if (scrollTopPosition>=positions[i]) { count = i; break; }

    }
});
```

notice that I add the pages height to the top position, this is necessary because the last section is shorter than the page height. You can experiment with removing

```
+$("#page").height()
```

but the for it to work you'll need to make sure the 3rd section has enough space bellow it to allow its header to scroll to the top like the other section.